# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, datastax

I am trying to configure spring data with cassandra.
But I am getting bellow error , when my app is deploying in tomcat.

When I check the connection, it is available to the given port. (127.0.0.1:9042). I have include stack trace and spring configuration bellow.
Does anyone having idea on this error?

Full stack trace :

```
2015-12-06 17:46:25 ERROR web.context.ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1230)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:157)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:278)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:43)
```

===================================================================

Spring Configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans ...>

    <cassandra:cluster id="cassandraCluster"
                       contact-points="127.0.0.1" port="9042" />
    <cassandra:converter />

    <cassandra:session id="cassandraSession" cluster-ref="cassandraCluster"
                       keyspace-name="blood" />

    <cassandra:template id="cqlTemplate" />


    <cassandra:repositories base-package="com.blood.dao.nosql" />
    <cassandra:mapping entity-base-packages="com.blood.domain.nosql" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: did you figure this out in the end? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Will, No I didn't. I also guess this is due to incompatibility of the versions.

Comment: @Harsha Hi! did you figure this out in the end?  after 3 years?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that Spring Data Cassandra (as of December 2015 when I write this) does not provide support for Cassandra 3.x. Here's an excerpt from a conversation with one of the developers in the #spring channel on freenode:

> [13:49] <_amicable> Hi all, does anybody know if spring data cassandra supports cassandra 3.x? All dependencies & datastax drivers seem to be 2.x
>
> [13:49] <@_ollie> amicable: Not in the near future.
>
> [13:49] <_amicable> _ollie: thanks.
>
> [13:50] <_amicable> I'll go and look at the relative merits of 2.x vs 3.x then 
>   ;)
>
> [13:51] <@_ollie> SD Cassandra is a community project (so far) and its progress highly depends on how much time the developers can actually spend on it.
>
> [13:51] <@_ollie> We will have someone joining the team in February 2016 to get the project more closely aligned to the core Spring Data projects.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using an older version of the driver with Cassandra 3.0. Cassandra 3.0 changed its internal schema metadata representation, and only the latest drivers can parse this metadata.

Use Java Cassandra driver [3.0.0-alpha5](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.datastax.cassandra%7Ccassandra-driver-core%7C3.0.0-alpha5%7Cbundle) to connect to Cassandra 3.0.

Comment: Thanks Adam, But this didn't work. I am using 'spring-data-cassandra' maven dependency, which internally refers lower version of Cassandra driver. Even I added cassandra 3.0.0-alpha5, it throws errors in spring.

Comment: For the record, errors such as `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;`

Comment: Note: This is mentioned in the Datastax upgrade document for 3.0.0 (released) here http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/upgrade_guide/. This is the note from the document "These methods must now be invoked on TypeCodec directly. To resolve the TypeCodec instance for a particular data type, use CodecRegistry#codecFor." Hope it helps anyone trying to fix it themselves. Other APIs that breaks are also mentioned in this document.

Comment: They moved the aforementioned upgrade guide to: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/upgrade_guide/