# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table user"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I am new to Cassandra and this has been giving me issues. I downloaded apache-Cassandra 3.11 and I am using spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE. I did some research and found a [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117374/com-datastax-driver-core-exceptions-invalidqueryexception-unconfigured-table-sc) where it says it may be because Spring data is using a different Cassandra driver core version? But the latest uses cql 3 correct? I also made a java class configuration file. The issue may be here.

```
import org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.cassandra.config.DataCenterReplication;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration{
    private static final String KEYSPACE = "my_keyspace";

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean bean = new CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean();
        bean.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
        return bean;
    }

    /**
     * if it dont exist , create it
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return KEYSPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[]{"com.cassandra"};
    }

    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> createKeyspaceSpecifications = new ArrayList<>();
        createKeyspaceSpecifications.add(getKeySpaceSpecification());
        return createKeyspaceSpecifications;
    }

    // Below method creates "my_keyspace" if it doesnt exist.
    private CreateKeyspaceSpecification getKeySpaceSpecification() {
        CreateKeyspaceSpecification pandaCoopKeyspace = new CreateKeyspaceSpecification();
        DataCenterReplication dcr = new DataCenterReplication("dc1", 3L);
        pandaCoopKeyspace.name(KEYSPACE);
        pandaCoopKeyspace.ifNotExists(true).createKeyspace().withNetworkReplication(dcr);
        return pandaCoopKeyspace;
    }


    @Override
    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "localhost";
    }
}
```

This is the bean am trying to use

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

import java.util.UUID;

@Table("user")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    private UUID id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(UUID id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If you need more information, let me know, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could share the full stack-trace or the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `user` table into keyspace `my_keyspace`

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName text,
    lastName text
);
```

Comment: why `@Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return KEYSPACE;
    }` don't work?

Comment: @Alexandr the problem was with table.