# Cassandra Java driver 2.1.9 returns "InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, cqlsh

I have created a cluster called test with three nodes in my machine using ccm (All the nodes are UP). I want to access the cluster using Java API.

However, I get the error below:

> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces)

Cassandra version : 3.11.4

cassandra driver core : 2.1.9

Part of my code :

```java
public static void main(String args[])
{
     //creating Cluster object
     Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();

     //Creating Session object
     Session session = cluster.connect();
}
```

Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema\_keyspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117374/com-datastax-driver-core-exceptions-invalidqueryexception-unconfigured-table-sc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently schema_keyspaces isnt available in the specified cassandra version. I suggest to utilize the latest cassandra drivers , since that it is compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1 of the Cassandra Java driver is not compatible with Apache Cassandra 3.11 (see the [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/doc/java-drivers.html)).

You will need to upgrade to at least Java driver v3.0 to connect to a Cassandra 3.11 cluster. Cheers!